# REGEX in java: Not able to to detect newlines using ^ in a multiline mode

Tags: java, regex

I have a String:

```
*abc*
**def**
***ghi***
```

I want to remove all the astericks on the beginning of a newline newline.
Output should be:

```
abc*
def**
ghi***
```

I used a regex: `^\\*+`

But it removes all the astericks in the string! I couldn't understand why.

My code:

```
String input="*abc*\n**def**\n***hij***";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(^(\\*+))", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m=p.matcher(input);

while(m.find())
{input=input.replace(m.group(1), "");
}
System.out.println(input);
```

Comment: `m.group(1)` isn't "that bunch of asterisks over there". It's a string with a sequence of asterisks in it, and `input.replace` will replace all sequences of asterisks that look like `m.group(1)` instead of just the specific match you wanted to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `(?m)` switch and only one line is needed:

```
input = input.replaceAll("(?m)^\\*+", "");
```

That switch turns on "Caret and dollar match after and before newlines for the remainder of the regular expression".

---

Here's some test code:

```
String input = "*abc*\n**def**\n***hij***";
input = input.replaceAll("(?m)^\\*+", "");
System.out.println(input);
```

Output:

```
abc*
def**
ghi***
```

Comment: It's `(?m)` switch. `(?s)` is for `DOTALL`.

Comment: @RohitJain I often get them mixed up :/.  Thx.

Comment: Same here. Those are actually confusing. :)

Comment: but what if i dont want to replace the whole regular expression but just a part of it? isnt that why we use m.group()?

Comment: In the case where you want to keep parts of the expression, you can put back groups into the replacement string by using a *back reference* in the form `$n` where "n" is the group number. For example, `"a=b".replaceAll("(.)=(.)", "$2=$1")` results in `"b=a"`

Answer (score 3):

> But it removes all the astericks in the string! I couldn't understand why.

It's happening because of the `replace()` you do inside the `while` loop. If your pattern is found in the string, the the `group(1)` will contain the `\\*+` part without the `^`. So, if you replace `*`, it will replace all the `*` in the string.

For the 2nd time, it matches `**` at the beginning. And then you replace `group(1)` which is `**`, and will also replace `**` at the end. Remember, [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method replaces all the occurrences. Try changing the 2nd line of your string to - `**def***`, and you will see that it will leave a single `*` at the end.

Since you just have to replace you don't have to use that while loop and the `find()` method. Simply use [`Matcher#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29) method. Your regex is completely fine and you don't need any capture group there:

```
Pattern.compile("^\\*+", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input).replaceAll("");
```

---

This can also be done with the simple [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). For that you can use `(?m)` flag expression in regex, which is equivalent to [`Pattern.MULTILINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE):

> Multiline mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?m).

So, just do:

```
input = input.replaceAll("(?m)^\\*+", "");
```